# GCC virtual memory exhausted: Permission denied

Tags: c++, gcc, build

I'm trying to compile a particular .cpp file in a large project, and I'm getting the following error from GCC:

> virtual memory exhausted: Permission
>   denied

The file in question is ~25k in size, and less than 600 lines of C++ code.

I understand what it means to run out of virtual memory, but I'm not sure what the "Permission denied" qualifier means - my build machine doesn't appear to be running out of memory during the build, and ulimit shows unlimited virtual memory.

Any ideas for correcting this, either through system config, or suggestions for tracking down the offending code?

Note that adjusting GCC build flags is not an option.

Comment: How large is this "particular .cpp file?"  How much memory is the compiler using when it exits?  Remember that it may have an address space that is smaller than the total amount of memory on the system.  Have you tried tweaking the compiler options or modifying the .cpp file to see what you can do to prevent this problem from happening?

Comment: I've updated the question with file size information. I've tried removing any non-trivial code from the file with no luck. Modifying and tweaking compiler options are not an option - it's the "Permission denied" that has me most confused, I'm not sure how to interpret that.

Comment: Are your files being compiled and the folders where object files are being created have the proper permissions for your profile ?

Comment: Which version of gcc are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I've since corrected the issue by splitting some of the included .hpp files into multiple parts, and only #including the parts I need in this file. It makes sense to me why that fixes the virtual memory exhaustion, still not sure where permissions were failing though...